# Verify process is an Ito process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $(\xi(t),t\ge 0)$ be an Ito process with $\xi(0)=\theta$ and $$ d\xi(t)=\kappa(\theta-\xi(t))dt+\sigma\sqrt{\xi(t)}dW(t)$$ for $\kappa, \theta, \sigma \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $(\eta(t),t\ge 0)$, where $\eta(t):=t\xi(t)^2$, is an Ito process and give the stochastic differential $d\eta(t)$.

I know one can define $F(t,x):=t x^2$ and then apply the generalized Ito-formula to get $$d\eta(t)=\left(\xi(t)^2+2t\xi(t)\kappa(\theta-\xi(t))+t\sigma^2\xi(t)\right)dt+2t\sigma\xi(t)^{\frac{3}{2}}dW(t).$$

Since $\xi(t)$ is an Ito process it holds that $$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T\sigma^2\xi(t)dt \right]<\infty \text{, for every } T>0.$$

However, in order to show that $\eta(t)$ is indeed an Ito process we need to show that $$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T4t^2\sigma^2\xi(t)^3dt \right]<\infty \text{, for every } T>0.$$

This is where I am stuck. Is there something I am missing when $\sigma\ne 0$?

In the end I want to show that $$\int_0^T\mathbb{E}\left[\xi(t)^3\right]dt<\infty \text{, for every } T>0.$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: I would naively say that from  $\eta(t):=t\xi(t)^2$ you have $d\eta=\xi^2 dt +2\xi d\xi$. By using the initial SDE $d\xi =\kappa(\theta-\xi )dt+\sigma\sqrt{\xi }dW $, you have: $d\eta= [\xi^2 +2 \xi \kappa(\theta-\xi ) ]dt + 2 \xi \sigma\sqrt{\xi }dW $. Now just replace $\xi$ with $\xi(t)= \sqrt{\eta(t)/t}$ in the RHS. This is very non rigorous, I am not sure about it.

Comment: @Quillo is on the right track but instead of the usual chain rule you must use Itô's rule

Comment: @Chaos yep, I was suspecting that Ito 's lemma should be used, thanks for the hint! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma

Comment: You should follow the same procedure outlined here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3670224/532409

Comment: Hello tommeper21, you can have a look here, pag 31 of the pdf file, "Square-Root Process" https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~lyuu/finance1/2012/20120418.pdf . Related questions ("CIR" model) : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3714086/532409 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4368419/532409 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13482/532409 . See also Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model